# Dynamic content-type creation

Tags: 7, nodes, users

I have this scenario in my application:

Every registered member, can manage up to 3 content-types. And manage nodes based on their own content-types. They can manage their own content-types and nodes.

edit: the number of registered members might reach more than 1000

How can I approach this?

opening *administer content-types* permission for authenticated-users is definitely not an option. Also there could be a lot of confusions regarding dynamic permission, custom roles, etc...

Is creating content-type of node-content-types possible?

Are there any contributed modules or distribution for this specific features?

Thanks

edit02: Some explanations, I hope it's clear..

- user can manage his content-types by: creating new content type, edit/delete existing ones. he also can manage his nodes too.
- also, different user, cannot see other's content-types, but can see other's published nodes
- All content types (and it's fields) shouldn't be overlapped. maybe the user's name is included in the content-type machine name generator (and field's) to avoid duplicates
- I'm not sure about the idea *"creating content-type of node-content-type"*

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "manage content types" (what kind of "management"? Can there be any "overlap" between the 3 content types of any 2 users? Are those nodes assumed to be of a either of these 3 content types? What do you mean by "creating content-type of node-content-type"? Consider adding a few samples to make your question easier to understand ...

Comment: ok thanks for your input. I have updated my question. I'm not sure about the idea "creating content-type of node-content-type". It's kinda like "I create a content-type, but the node from it, is also a content-type"... pretty confusing lol...

Comment: With this extra edit things are quite a bit more clear (all of a sudden you now have TWO answers ...). Any chance to provide some more details about that "max of 3"? Like what if somebody tries to create a 4th one, how to prevent that, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this could be done, but I think it's too broad for the Q&A approach of Drupal Answers. In general, if I was to try this, I would start with this:

- add an integer field to the user (to track number of content types)
- using [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions), hide that field from anyone but admin

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set
>   field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.

- create a role with the appropriate permissions to add content types
- if permission allows viewing the content type list, use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to check that url against role to ensure new 'content type moderators' cannot access the list and redirect with a message

> The Rules module allows site administrators to define conditionally
>   executed actions based on occurring events (known as reactive or ECA
>   rules). It's a replacement with more features for the trigger module
>   in core and the successor of the Drupal 5 workflow-ng module.

- override the [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to check the integer value of the hidden field on content type creation, redirect or show message if user is at limit
- override the form submit() function to increment the integer value of the hidden field on content type creation, and create perhaps a custom block, menu entry or other element to allow the user access to edit the content type later on

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to consider: [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) (with permissions like "registered users can create their own group, of which they are the *owner*, so that they can "manage" whatever is related to that group).

Probably combined with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) (like to automate some things trigger by Organic groups related "events") and/or [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) (to secure group related "stuff", e.g. as a rules related "action" ) ...

Not sure yet if you'd need anything related to the [Flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag) module (which is often used in combination with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)). In your case anything related to "user specific, which might not be possible / handled by the [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) module.

Depending on how your question can further be enhanced (more specific about what you actually want), I might be able to further enhance this answer also.

Comment: I havent used OG before, I'll check it out. Meanwhile, I found module entityform, it seems to be what I need. I'd add some custom module to support it to handle the permission and limitations...

Answer (score -1):

Try and see if Webform: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform does what you want to achieve.